# Animate text one by one of UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

how to display text of textview one by one with animation, but I don't know how to do that.
For animate the textview is ok, but no luck for text.

I need help, and thank for answering !

Comment: Hi, Can you elaborate it more, and post some of your current codes

Comment: So you have a string of text and you want each character appear over a period of time, and as each character appears it animates in from 0 alpha to 1, then the next appears?